# Make python code compact - LOOP to JSON Path

Tags: python, json

This is my sample code:

```
   st = loadedJSON

    if len(value) == 1:
        x = st[value[0]]['sample']

    elif len(value) == 2:
        x = st[value[0]][value[1]]['sample']

    elif len(value) == 3:
        x = st[value[0]][value[1]][value[2]]['sample']
```

I'm not sure how to convert this code into something like:

```
value = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
st = loadedJSON
y = len(value)
# Need to create like this
x = st["1"]["2"]["3"]["4"]["5"]["6"]['sample']
# Bigger VALUE = Bigger JSON Keys Path
```

Is it any specific function that converts ARRAY to JSON Key Path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```py
node = st
for step in value:
    node = node[step]
x = node['sample']
```